# Swift: Display image by URL saved in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to display a list of store names, descriptions and images in my table cells like below:

[image]

I created my storyboard like this:

[image]

And this is what I've got so far:

[image]

I store the data in Firebase in below format

[image]

Created a data model that fits Firebase data

```
for stores in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
    let storeObject = stores.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    let storeName = storeObject?["storeName"]
    let storeDesc = storeObject?["storeDesc"]
    let storeUrl = storeObject?["storeUrl"]

    let store = StoreModel(
        name: storeName as! String?, 
        desc: storeDesc as! String?, 
        url: storeUrl as! String?)

    self.storeList.append(store)
}
```

Display data

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let store: StoreModel

    store = storeList[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelName.text = store.name
    cell.labelDesc.text = store.desc

    return cell
}
```

I've successfully displayed the list of store names and descriptions, but don't know how to display the images by URL I store in Firebase.

I've tried below code in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` function, but it didn't work

```
let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: store.url)!
let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

cell.imageStore.image = image
```

Error messages:

```
Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'
Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no key "storeUrl" in store object. I see a "storePic".

Comment: @Muhammad Zohaib Ehsan Hi, sorry I changed the firebase data format but forgot to update the post's screenshot. Just updated the post, thank you!

Comment: Did you connect your image view to an outlet in the cell? Can you check your outlet? Also add a break point, where you create the image and check if image is dowloaded or not.

Comment: @Muhammad Zohaib Ehsan Hi I did connect the image view to the outlet. I also update the post with the error messages for reference. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a suggestion you should avoid force unwrap and use Swift types, for example Data instead of NSData :) then, the code you tried works synchronously and it’s better to download your images asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI, try using URLSession, you can create a UIImageView extension, for example:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setImage(from urlAddress: String?) {
        guard let urlAddress = urlAddress, let url = URL(string: urlAddress) else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in this way:

```
cell.imageView.setImage(from: storeUrl)
```